# Google sites and Google App Engine Integration

Tags: google-app-engine, iframe, google-sites

1. I have deployed a few static html pages through Google app engine which works fine as expected (Access rights reserved to a specific domain).
2. Embedded those pages in Google site through the i frames(insert -> gadgets -> iframe and include url) which works fine only if an instance of the application on Google app engine is started by that particular machine, but if that's not the case, i frames won't display anything.

Which means if there is no instance of the application started by a particular machine (myApplication.appspot.com), it wont work while what i think is it should start an instance by itself on opening of the Google site page because i frame on that page already links it to the page on App engine. 
Can anybody please explain as to why is this happening and suggest some work around for it..

Comment: Hello , your application work  in your url   --- http://myApplication.appspot.com/page.hml ?

Comment: No that is just an example i provided, but the application name is something else whose access rights are protected to my company's domain